# Error integrating OpenID in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, dotnetopenauth

I am trying to use OpenID in my website using asp.net_c#. I downloaded the latest version of dotnetopenauth 3.4.7 from http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/
On referencing the binary DotNetOpenAuth.dll from the toolbox, visual studio gives me an error saying there was an error loading types from assembly DotNetOpenAuth.dll and also error in loading system.web.mvc

Please note that I am not developing an MVC website. I am working on asp.net forms website with asp.net v4. Is the dll only for mvc websites???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Visual Studio is throwing the errors because it can't find the dependencies required by `DotNetOpenAuth`. You can install the MVC framework, just so that Visual Studio has the dependencies, but you don't have to use MVC in your project.

Comment: Here is a thread that discusses this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dotnetopenid/zAPjhLFBJ-Q  Using the toolbox is a very convenient thing, so following this advice will enable you to do so.

Comment: under what namespace does openidexception comes?

Comment: is openidselector no longer a free version?? Could not get the code from idselector.com   :(

Comment: the openidselector from the toolbox control doesn't seem to work, giving jscript runtime error...

Comment: @Jayesh - Has your question been about VS having trouble loading the MVC library been answered? The openidselector seems to be a different question, so you should create a new question, with more details on your runtime error.

Comment: @keyboardP - I've marked your answer and posted the problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239256/openidselector-problem-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 2):

The DotNetOpenAuth.dll file will work perfectly well in a WebForms page.  It is not necessary to add it to your toolbox.  Instead, put the DLL into your `/bin` folder and reference it from your code.

There is a decent walkthrough of this process [here](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/programmatic-openid-relying-party/).

Comment: In the walkthrough the ClaimsRequest method is showing me reference error. Under which class should i reference it?

Comment: Even the DemandLevel and OpenIdException does not exist in the context :X

Comment: ClaimsRequest and DemandLevel are both under DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Extensions.SimpleRegistration.  I don't have an OpenIdException in my installation, but I am probably not on the most recent version.  You should be able to open the DLL in Visual Studio's object browser and search its contents for the objects you are looking for. It will tell you what context they are in.