# OpenIDSelector problem in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, dotnetopenauth

I am trying to use OpenID in my website using asp.net_c#. I am working on asp.net forms website with asp.net v4. The issue i am having is with openidselector control from my toolbox generated from dotnetopenauth.dll. It does not work and not even displays. Any help?

code:

Comment: BTW, your question is not so helpful for others. You should consider adding some code that you are working on.

Comment: haven't really done any coding, just drag n drop of the tools:

code:

    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <rp:OpenIdLogin ID="OpenIdLogin1" runat="server">
            </rp:OpenIdLogin>
            <rp:OpenIdSelector ID="OpenIdSelector1" runat="server">
            </rp:OpenIdSelector>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>

Comment: give this one a try : http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/

Comment: I am also getting a JScript runtime error in IE8 but not in Firefox & Chrome. The lengthy error code mentions "openid_identifier" in error.

Comment: I have worked on the sample given in the link you posted which is of mvc application, but i am working on a web forms project.

Comment: you should implement the feature on plain html and javascript in my opinion. That way it would be healthier. After that implement your logic on code behind. Also look at my answer update. I put a sample link for you.

Comment: Please look at this [error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242724/openid-links-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the following one and it is really great. But you need to figure out most of the stuff to work with your asp.net logic;

http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/

**EDIT**
Also this could be helpful;

http://bhaidar.net/post/2011/04/04/OpenID-Single-Sign-On-ASPNET-Web-Forms.aspx

Comment: Please look at [this error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242724/openid-links-error)