# OpenID links error

Tags: c#, asp.net, openid, openid-selector

I am trying to integrate openid authentication in asp.net 4 following this [article](http://bhaidar.net/post/2011/04/04/OpenID-Single-Sign-On-ASPNET-Web-Forms.aspx). I have proceeded as was demonstrated in the article. The problem i face is that only openid login link works. All other links gives an error:
`Precondition failed.: userSuppliedIdentifier != null`

I have uploaded the page [here](http://www.eprocerp.com/OpenIDLogin.aspx). Also the openid selector from the toolbox doesn't work as i have asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239256/openidselector-problem-in-asp-net). Kindly reply.

Comment: When you get the response back from the OpenID OP are you handling that response and storing the user's claimed_identity somewhere?

Comment: I am storing the fetched response in a session variable. I am displaying the friendly identifier in a label which you can see in the [link i shared](http://www.eprocerp.com/OpenIDLogin.aspx), if u sign in using open id.
But is the problem due to handling of response or is it due to sending of response? or do i have to edit the javascript files as google & yahoo links are also not opening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are following the example you referred to then in method HandleRelyingPartyRequest, change this line:

var request = openid.CreateRequest(Request.Form["openid_identifier"]);
**to**

var request = openid.CreateRequest(Request.Form["openid_username"]);

and also remove any general exception you have in that method. That should resolve the issue.

Thanks,
Raju

Comment: Nope. [Same error](http://www.eprocerp.com/OpenIDLogin.aspx). Btw, what diff does the form name here makes? In aspx file the div-openid_inputarea has an input id="openid_identifier", as given in the example.