# OpenID Selector for asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, openid, openid-selector

I am trying to integrate openid authentication in asp.net 4 and have followed the following articles:

1. [Article 1](http://bhaidar.net/post/2011/04/04/OpenID-Single-Sign-On-ASPNET-Web-Forms.aspx)
2. [Article 2](http://danhounshell.com/blog/adding-openid-to-your-web-site-in-conjunction-with-asp-net-membership/)

I have uploaded the page [here](http://www.eprocerp.com/OpenIDLogin.aspx) and the problem is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242724/openid-links-error).

I want to implement the openID selector as given in https://www.idselector.com/ but i didn't get any response from the site nor did the OpenIdSelector control from the dotnetopenauth toolbox worked. Can anyone share the openid selector as given in https://www.idselector.com/? Or any help regarding the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242724/openid-links-error) would be grateful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the DotNetOpenAuth library instead of rolling out your own.

http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

They also provide project templates which can integrated into a website.

Comment: offcourse I am using  the same, through which i populated the openID toolbox controls.

Comment: That didn't work for me, and i have switched to [social auth-net](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-net/)

Comment: What issue you face @Jayesh